# Bootstrap columns in a php while loop not working

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

Currently, my products are displaying in one column but I'd like them to display in either a 3 or 4 column grid. Here's the code I have so far.

```
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
        $totalResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $searchResultHTML = '';

        if ($totalResult > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $searchResultHTML .= '
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <article class="aa-properties-item">
                                <a href="#" class="aa-properties-item-img">
                                    <img src="img/preventas/' . $row['RutaImagen'] . '"  alt="img" class="img-responsive" >
                                </a>
                                <div class="aa-tag for-sale">
                                    Entrega: Inmediata
                                </div>
                                <div class="aa-properties-item-content">
                                    <div class="aa-properties-info">
                                        <span>' . $row['Num_Habitaciones'] . ' Cuartos</span>
                                        <span>' . $row['Num_Banios'] . ' Baños</span>
                                        <span>Desde ' . $row['Metros_Cuadrados_Desde'] . ' m<sup>2</sup></span>
                                        <span>Hasta ' . $row['Metros_Cuadrados_Hasta'] . ' m<sup>2</sup></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="aa-properties-about">
                                        <h3>10 Departamentos</h3>
                                        <p>En una elegante torre de 18 pisos rodeados de terrazas con jardines y áreas comunes incomparables que brindan increíbles espacios abiertos para vivir y crear experiencias.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="aa-properties-detial">
                                        <span class="aa-price">
                                            Desde $' . $row['Precio'] . ' 
                                        </span>
                                        <a href="#" class="aa-secondary-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Detalles</button></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                    </div>';
            }
        } else {
            $searchResultHTML = '<h3>No se ha encontrado ningún resultado..</h3>';
        }
        return $searchResultHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML and CSS. I don't see what this question has to do with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
 function foo($id){

  ...
  $results = [];

  $datas= mysqli_query(...);
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datas)) {
    $results[] = $result;   
  }

  return $results;
}
```

```
$results= foo($id);

foreach($results as $result) {
    //use $result
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this is. Why are you not using `fetch_all()`? How does it answer the question?